# Convert EDI format to csv using scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to convert EDI format file to CSV file using spark or scala?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like [this](https://www.altova.com/mapforce) to create a mapping from EDI format to CSV and then generate a code in that tool. This code then can be used to convert EDI to CSV in Spark.

Comment: thanks for your reply that tool which you shared is not open source. is their any other alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

For open source solutions, I think your best bet is [EDI Reader from BerryWorks](https://github.com/BerryWorksSoftware/edireader). Haven't tried it myself, but apparently [this is what Hortonworks recommends](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/59975/ingesting-edi-into-hdfs-using-hdf-20.html), and I'd trust their judgement in the Big Data area. I'm not involved with either, for the matters of disclosure.

From there, it's still a matter of converting EDI XML representation to CSV. Given that XML processing is not part of vanilla Spark, again, your options are rather limited here. Try [Databricks spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) maybe?